# Bootstrap 5 RTL, In LTR language (when changing locale) Not working correctly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```
    <div class="top-row1" dir="@direction">
        <div class="row px-2">
                               
            <div class="offset-8 col-4 text-end">
                <div class="pe-2 pt-2 d-inline-block">
                    <select id="selectLanguage" @onchange="@((e) => LanguageChanged(e))">
                     ...                  
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Using Bootstrap5.rtl when I run Above code and selected language is an rtl language (@direction="rtl") the page shows as expected, But when language is english (@direction="ltr") the page is messed up.

In bootstrap 4 including only bootstrap.rtl version was sufficient for both rtl and ltr languages, Now that bootstrap 5 introduce -start and -end instead of -left and -right the page is not working correctly.

am I have to use both bootstrap versions depending on direction, Or is there a way to make ltr work?

Comment: it seems bootstrap5 is not like bootstrap4 and I should include both files in the project and depending on direction load the appropriate file so this line of code solve dmy problem: <link href=@($"css/bootstrap/bootstrap5-{direction}.min.css") rel="stylesheet" />